# Should I prune other veggies the same way I prune tomatoes?

Tags: vegetables, pruning

I just finished pruning the foliage on my tomato plants and am wondering if other plants in the garden would benefit from a similar trim?

In particular, my eggplant and peppers have very dense leaves and honestly, cutting the leaves back would help me keep track of how ripe the veggies are.  I don't want to hurt or stunt the plants though.  And what about other veggies?

[image]

Comment: I don't know why doing this would hurt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RAjQTb4QvnA

Comment: My goodness, these are beautiful plants.  What fertilizer are you using?  Looks like too much nitrogen, there isn't a reproductive bud in sight.  Way too much nitrogen.  Yes, you should thin these leaves as the aeration is horrible this dense but you have to change your fertilizer.  No way should there be these many leaves.  You have to have used too much nitrogen versus phosphorus and potassium.

Answer (score 2):

It's Forrest. I think your leafy eggplants and rotting zukes are related. I wonder if you have nutrient imbalance in your soil. Too much nitrogen, not enough other stuff. Blossom end rot is caused by too little of one nutrient (either calcium or phosphorus, I think.) I think the cucumber beetles are probably a red herring. I see them all ove the place in my garden. I think they just like the tastes of squash.

By the way, I don't see any harm in pruning these.